# Delphi: How to send an Array of Variant from DLL to Application using Windows API "SendMessage"?

Tags: delphi, winapi, dll, sendmessage

I need to send data from DLL to App, where "data" is an array of variant.

I tried to use SendMessage / WM_COPYDATA, with no luck!

This is what I get so far:

```
// sender's side (dll)
procedure sendData(apphandle: THandle);
var V: Variant;
begin
    V = VarArrayOf([1,'Some Text', 123.45, true]);
    copyDataStruct.dwData := 100;
    copyDataStruct.cbData := ?; <-- what here?
    copyDataStruct.lpData := ?; <-- and here? how to put "V"?
    SendMessage(apphandle, WM_COPYDATA, Integer(apphandle), Integer(@copyDataStruct)) ;
end;


// receiver's side (same app where dll was called)
procedure WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData) ;
var V : Variant;
begin
    if (Msg.CopyDataStruct.dwData = 100) then
    begin
        V := Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData; <-- how to get "V" from lpData?
        // do some work with "V" here...
    end;
end;
```

Comment: `WM_COPYDATA` sends a single chunk of contiguous data. A Delphi array is unlikely to be structured like that.

Comment: Serialize the array and use WM_COPYDATA. Or use COM for an easy life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the app and DLL are using the same version of the RTL, and you are passing the `Variant` around inside the same process, you can pass it as a pointer, eg:

```
procedure sendData(AppHandle: HWND);
var
  V: Variant;
begin
  V := VarArrayOf([1,'Some Text', 123.45, true]);
  copyDataStruct.dwData := 100;
  copyDataStruct.cbData := SizeOf(Pointer);
  copyDataStruct.lpData := @V;
  SendMessage(AppHandle, WM_COPYDATA, WPARAM(AppHandle), LPARAM(@copyDataStruct));
end;

procedure WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  V : PVariant;
begin
  if (Msg.CopyDataStruct.dwData = 100) then
  begin
    V := PVariant(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
    // use V^ as needed...
  end;
end;
```

In which case, you could drop `WM_COPYDATA` and just use a custom window message instead:

```
const
  WM_MYMSG = WM_APP + 1;

procedure sendData(AppHandle: HWND);
var
  V: Variant;
begin
  V := VarArrayOf([1,'Some Text', 123.45, true]);
  SendMessage(AppHandle, WM_MYMSG, 0, LPARAM(@V));
end;

procedure WMMyMsg(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  V : PVariant;
begin
  V := PVariant(Msg.LParam);
  // use V^ as needed...
end;
```